# integrate differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Maybe a silly question but I would like to integrate an equation of the form, the limits being some initial time $t_i$ and some final time $t_f$:

$\frac{\dot{x}(t)}{x(t)} = \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t)} -2 \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{b(t)} - \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t) + b(t)}$

Just having the term on the left and the first term on the right is very easy, but I'm not sure of how to do the integration for the second and third terms on the right hand side. The only condition I know is that some function $f(t) = a(t) + b(t)$ and $\dot{f}(t) = \dot{a}(t) + \dot{b}(t)$.

The things I know: $x(t=0)=x_{i}$, $a(t=0) = a_{i}$, $a(t=t_{f}) = a_{f}$, $b(t=0) = b_{i}$, $b(t=t_{f}) = b_{f}$, which are basically numbers. I also know the functions $\dot{a}(t)$ and  $\dot{b}(t)$, which are just constants. I know the numbers for the initial and final $a$, $b$. If I was just integrating, $\frac{\dot{x}(t)}{x(t)} = \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t)}$, the integration gives me: $x_f = x_i \frac{a_{f}}{a_{i}}$. And I know all the values on the right hand side, which are just numbers, so I can compute $x_{f}$. My problem is just the integration of the last term in the first equation

Comment: What is known and what is unknown ?

Comment: I wrote the things I know in the question.

Comment: You wrote : "the functions $\dot{a}(t)$ and  $\dot{b}(t)$ are just constants." So, $\dot{a}(t)=c_1\quad\to\quad a(t)=c_1t+c_2$ and $\dot{b}(t)=c_3\quad\to\quad b(t)=c_3t+c_4$. Thus $\frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t) + b(t)}=\frac{c_1}{(c1+c_3)t+c_2+c_4}$ which is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\dot a\equiv A$ and $\dot b\equiv B$ are constants, you can write $a=At+a_i$ and $b=Bt+b_i$. Then your equation reads
$$
\frac{\dot x}{x} = \frac{A}{At+a_i}-\frac{2A}{Bt+b_i}-\frac{A}{(A+B)t+a_i+b_i}
$$
and integrates to
$$
\log(x)+C = \log(At+a_i) - 2\frac{A}{B}\log(Bt+b_i)-\frac{A}{A+B}\log\big((A+B)t+a_i+b_i\big)\,,
$$
for a suitable constant $C$.